# Calling child class method from parent

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Is it possible for the a.doStuff() method to print "B did stuff" without editing the A class? If so, how would I do that?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.doStuff();
        b.doStuff();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A did stuff");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B did stuff");
    }
}
```

I'm modding a steam game, Terraria. And I don't want to decompile and recompile it all because that will screw with steam. My program 'injects' into Terraria via XNA. I can use the update() and draw() methods from XNA to mod some things. But it's pretty limited. I wan't to override base methods to mod more things (worldgen for example).

Answer (score 20):

Yes, if you declare `doStuff` as `virtual` in `A` and then `override` in `B`.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A did stuff");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B did stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since A.doStuff is just there to be overridden it should be abstract rather than virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Since B is effectively A through inheritance and the method is overloaded.

```
A a = new B();
a.doStuff();
```

Comment: of course it can be done by virtual and override, but this is the only way to do it without changing A as requested OP

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do that either. I probably should've clarified this in the OP; I'm modding a steam game, Terraria. And I don't want to decompile and recompile it all because that will screw with steam. My program 'injects' into Terraria via XNA. I can use the update() and draw() methods from XNA to mod some things. But it's pretty limited. I wan't to override base methods to mod more things (worldgen for example).

Comment: @user1178494 see my updated answer with use of new keyword that might help.

Comment: if my assumption is correct, you will be using XNA functions on Terraria and I think the best way is to use decorator patterns.

Comment: using OP's example, this will print `"A did stuff"`. `A.doStuff()` is not virtual -- `B` is not overriding it. And B is not overloading anything -- it's `hiding` the base class method with it's own (normally you would use `new` when that's the case).

Answer (score 0):

The code for class A & B you have posted will anyways generate below compiler warning and will ask to use the `new` keyword on class B, although it will compile:
***The keyword new is required on 'B.doStuff()' because it hides inherited member 'A.doStuff()'***

Use `method hiding` along with `new` and `virtual` keyword in class Mapper and class B as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper a = new B(); //notice this line
        B b = new B();

        a.doStuff();
        b.doStuff();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class A
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A did stuff");
    }
}

class Mapper : A
{
    new public virtual void doStuff() //notice the new and virtual keywords here which will all to hide or override the base class implementation
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mapper did stuff");
    }
}

class B : Mapper
{
    public override void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B did stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will still print "A did stuff" when calling a.doStuff().

Comment: @user1178494 I have updated my answer, pls try it and notice the use of Mapper (Mediator) class in between A and B classes, please see if it solves your problem..

Comment: @user1178494 Ok, can you try with Mapper a = new B(); as in updated answer, will this change be allowed for your solution? I suppose its the only way left for working solution..

Comment: That does work, but I still have to change the original game files, which isn't an option. I guess what I want isn't possible then? Thanks for helping me.